# Insert Dash between two odd number, how to convert int to string

Tags: java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static 
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import tester.DashSol;

pulbic class Dash {
       public static String insertDash(int num){
char[] numbers = str.tochararray();
String result = ""
    for(int = 1; 1 < numbers.length; i++){
        int value1 = character.getnumericvalue(numbers[i-1]);
        int value2 = character.getnumericvalue(number[i]);
        result += value1;
       if(value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0){
       result +="-";
    }
}
       result += numbers[numbers.length - 1];
}}
 return ""; 
 }
 }
```

whats the relation within "int num", char[]numbers ? i want to return the result in String type.

Comment: When asking a question, please make the effort to properly format your code.

Comment: `String str = Integer.toString(num);`

Comment: You could do `if ((numbers[i - 1] & numbers[i] & 1) == 1) result += '-';` ;)

Comment: If you don’t understand this invalid code, you probably should ask the author instead of us.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
Character.getNumericValue(...);
```

Just cast the values directly into integer

```
int value1 = (int)(numbers[i-1]);
int value2 = (int)(numbers[i]);
```

There were a few typos in your code as well. *insertDash* should look something like this in the end

```
char[] numbers = str.toCharArray();
String result = "";
for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++){
    int value1 = (int)(numbers[i-1]);
    int value2 = (int)(numbers[i]);
    result += value1;
    if(value1 % 2 != 0 && value2 % 2 != 0){
        result +="-";
    }
}          
result += numbers[numbers.length - 1];
   
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static String insertDashBetweenOddNumbers(long num) {
    String str = String.valueOf(num);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int cur = str.charAt(i) - '0';

        if (i > 0) {
            int prv = str.charAt(i - 1) - '0';

            if (isOdd(prv) && isOdd(cur))
                buf.append('-');
        }

        buf.append(cur);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}

private static boolean isOdd(int num) {
    return (num & 1) == 1;
}
```